# correct tense: [you swept] or [you had swept]

Tags: tense

I have made up the examples below.

(1) When was the first time you swept the floor?

(2) When was the first time you **had** swept the floor?

My non-native friends think (2) is the correct question. They gave me this explanation. They said usually people say things like "Today **is** the first time I **HAVE DONE** this." "Last Friday **was** the first time I **HAD DONE** this." Based on this logic, they believed that (2) was correct. Do you agree with them.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Both sentences are correct, with (slightly) different meanings.  (That is the answer to many questions of "which tense is correct".  The answer to such questions is often "both")

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.